# How do I print double in Python with exact precision?

Tags: python, double, precision

I need to print double with precision equal exactly to 6, I found function **round**:

```
print(str(round(result, 6))
```

But in case *result* itself has less precision, the print function skips zeros at the end.

Gor example, the output of such code,

```
print(str(round(4.0, 6)))
```

is

```
4.0
```

But what I need is

```
4.000000
```

How can I reach this?

Comment: `format(result, '.6f')`?

Answer (score 17):

Try using a format string:

```
print("%.6f"%4.0) # 4.000000
```

Or alternatively:

```
print("{:.6f}".format(4.0))
```

See [the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec) for details on format strings and more examples.